# Can't reach ActiveMQ from inside Docker container

Tags: docker, activemq-classic, dockerfile

I'm trying to access an ActiveMQ instance on my local machine from inside a docker container also running on my machine. AMQ is listening on `0.0.0.0:61616`. I tried to configure my program running in the container to use the ip address of `docker0` as well as `enp6s0`, both didn't work.

If I however use the `--net=host` option it suddenly works, no matter which ip address I use. The problem is that I can't use the option in production as the code that starts the container doesn't support this. So if it's not possible to change the default network in the Dockerfile, I have to fix this in a different way.

EDIT: My Dockerfile

```
FROM java:8-jre

RUN mkdir -p /JCloudService
COPY ./0.4.6-SNAPSHOT-SHADED/ /JCloudService

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install netcat -y && apt-get install nano

WORKDIR /JCloudService

CMD set -x; /bin/sh -c '/JCloudService/bin/JCloudScaleService'
```

And the run command: `docker run -it jcs:latest`. With this command it doesn't work. Only if I add `--net=host`

Comment: Are you publishing all exposed ports when starting the container?

Comment: Do I need to? I thought that I only need to publish ports on my local machine for activemq

Comment: Please post your Dockerfile / `docker run...` command

Comment: see edit for dockerfile and command

Answer (score 0):

`--net=host` works because it tells Docker to put your container in the same networking stack as your host machine.

To connect to a service running on your machine you need the ip of your host machine on the docker0 network. So `ip addr show docker0` on your host, then you should be able to use that IP and 61616 to connect to the host from within the container.

Comment: This didn't work. Note that ActiveMQ is not running in the docker. If I get it right, this opens the port `61616` _inside_ docker. The weird thing is, I can reach AMQ from inside the container using `nc 172.17.0.1 61616` (which is the `docker0` ip.

Comment: That's correct, edited answer (misread question, no coffee yet!). Also why not run AMQ in a container as well! Containerize _all_ the things! :)